# How to check if I am writing the right Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I know this question would look silly.

But I am new to the `Docker` and kinda ambiguous about **how to write a proper Docker file**

Docker file depends on what we are deploying on the container (PHP, nginx, node, etc.)

pulling an image is okay. But **How do we exactly know what `CMD` should be run and what `PATH` should be given?**

Some Dockerfiles don't need a `CMD` part. Some need `PATH` and some don't. How do we exaclt know this? Can we see this if we clicked on a `tag` in docker hub? I can see there is a `Dockerfile` for each tag. But that is a complex `Dockerfile`

How do we **exactly know which syntaxes (i.e. `PATH`, `CMD` etc...)** should write in the `Dockerfile` to make the deployment work?

Comment: I would suggest you read about whatever framwork/library you are deploying and reading about the docker documentation on docker files Here is a link for you to get started https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: You need to be clear with CMD first. Normally we run some service that runs continuously in CMD. If you are running nginx than simply you can run that in background mode using the cmd and you don't have to pass the path but you can do the same thing by writing the command to execute in a file and provide a path to it. If the commands to run becomes long I usually write it to a bash script and pass the path to CMD.

Answer (score 2):

most of this just come along with your knowledge and experience around the base image ecosystem.

Nevertheless, as @rahultyagi stated, **search the documentation** of your language for Dockerfile examples. most modern libs and frameworks come with an official Dockerfile you can refer to as your base image, and an example Dockerfile you can copy and tweak for your app.

a great tool ive recently run into is called [`hadolint`](https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint) and its kind of a linter for your dockerfiles. it also got an online version you can try: https://hadolint.github.io/hadolint/

[image]

my final own tip is to make as much dummy dockerfiles as you can on your free time, for tools and libraries you run into, until you get the hang of it.

Cheers & Good Luck!